# Returning Three Columns From Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and i want to return the three columns which will contains only the Count of the records according to the Today's Date, This Week and Current Month

```
SELECT count(*) as TotalCount 
FROM CalendarItem t 
LEFT JOIN company c ON t.companyID = c.companyID AND c.enabled = 1 
INNER JOIN CalendarItemType tt ON tt.CalendarItemtypeID = t.CalendarItemTypeID 
LEFT JOIN request r ON r.requestID=t.workrequestID 

where t.deleted = 0  + @where
```

And curretnly i am executing this Sp three time for Today week and month by passing different arg

```
@where =AND (t.startDate BETWEEN '2013-7-17' AND '2013-7-18')
```

and for week

```
@where = AND (t.startDate BETWEEN '2013-7-14 00:00:00' AND '2013-7-20')
```

and same for month

I want my SP return three counts according to the Today's Date , week date and MOnth

So any idea how should i do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when t.startDate BETWEEN '2013-7-17' AND '2013-7-18' then 1 else 0 end) as DayCount,
    sum(case when t.startDate BETWEEN '2013-7-14' AND '2013-7-20' then 1 else 0 end) as WeekCount,
    //month condition here
FROM CalendarItem t 
LEFT JOIN company c ON t.companyID = c.companyID AND c.enabled = 1 
INNER JOIN CalendarItemType tt ON tt.CalendarItemtypeID = t.CalendarItemTypeID 
LEFT JOIN request r ON r.requestID=t.workrequestID 

where t.deleted = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass Three output parameter to stored procedure, and set its value in sp, then easily you can get it back